# Dúvida com HandleError asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou pesquisando sobre uma forma de evitar uma mensagem de erro quando acontecer do usuário entra por uma página que precisa de um parâmetro:

```
namespace Projeto.WEB.Controllers
{
    public class ModalidadeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Modalidade
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();

        }

        [HandleError(ExceptionType = typeof(OverflowException), View = "Home" )]
        [HandleError()]
        public ActionResult SelecionarModalidade(int id)
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

O problema, se o usuário tenta entrar diretamente nesta página após a mesma estar gravada no seu computador. Neste caso teria alguma rota para direcionar o usuário informando que não foi possível ou direcionar ele para a `index`?

Fiz um teste:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error" />
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Este erro ocorre quando o parâmetro esperado é um tipo primitivo, ou seja, não é nullable.

Uma das formas de evitar este erro é tornando o parâmetro nullable.

```
public ActionResult SelecionarModalidade(int? id)
{
    if(!id.HasValue)
        return new RedirectResult("~/");

    return View();
}
```